# SelectNextControl always select Itself in DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have problems when using `SelectNextControl` method with `forward = true` in DevExpress (Window control worked well)

```
private void setUpDownNextControl(Control control)
    {
        control.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down) // Select it seft
            {
                SelectNextControl((Control)s, true, true, true, true);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up) // Work well !
            {   
                SelectNextControl((Control)s, false, true, true, true);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };
    }
```

Please help me :(

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: When "forward parameter = true", it's always select Itself
But when "forward parameter = false", it worked well ! :(

Comment: This code does nothing at all.  A control's KeyDown event never sees the cursor keys, they are intercepted before they get to the control.  Used by Winforms to allow the user to navigate between controls.  Same story for Tab and Shift+Tab.  Easy to check with the debugger, set a breakpoint on the SelectNextControl() calls.  You should probably focus on getting the TabIndex of the controls set correctly.  If you must override the normal navigation (this code doesn't) then you need to override ProcessCmdKey().  Be sure to not break a control that uses the cursor keys, like a multi-line textbox.